# Express res.sendFile() function returns a 204 no content response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to send an image using Express' sendFile() function. However currently it seems the function is not reading my file at all, and returns a 204 no content response.

Here is my function/ endpoint:

```
@httpGet('/pricereq')
  async getAllPriceChangeReqs(@response() res: express.Response) {
    try {
      const data = await this.priceService.compilePriceChangeRequests();
      const imagePath = path.resolve(data);
      console.log(path.isAbsolute(imagePath));
      console.log(imagePath);
      return res.sendFile(imagePath);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({ error: err.message });
    }
  }
```

The `data` variable here retrieves part of a path stored on a db. For example `uploads/receipt-2023-03-11T13-48-41.124Z.jpg` .

Then `imagePath` variable then retrieves the absolute path based on that partial path. So following on from the above example, `imagePath` would be `C:\Users\John\Desktop\Project\backend\uploads\receipt-2023-03-11T13-48-41.124Z.jpg`

I know this path is indeed absolute because of the following line: `console.log(path.isAbsolute(imagePath));` which returns true.

I also know that the path actually points to an image because if I go to it in file explorer it opens the image. I am using Windows 10 if that makes any difference.

Things I've tried:

- Place an image into the exact same directory as this function called `coffee.jpg`. Got the absolute path for that and tried to send that image. I did this because I thought my the `sendFile()` function didn't like the format of the name of my image. Didn't work
- Tried `res.sendFile(imagePath);` instead of `return res.sendFile(imagePath);`
- Tried multiple ways to call the endpoint. Postman and through browser. Same result.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Pass a second argument as `{ root : __dirname}` or `{ root: 'your-root-location'}` in sendFile